# create count matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have large dataframe as shown below with few rows and column:

```
    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
S1  2   4   2   6
S2  2   1   3   2
S3  2   2   2   2
S4  3   0   2   2
```

For each row i would need a matrix with count of each number in the range of ID value. Since the largest is 6 in ID values, it creates a matrix with 7 columns i.e. 0 to 6 and fill with the count values.

Sample Output:

```
    0   1   2   3    4    5    6
S1  0   0   2   0    1    0    1
S2  0   1   2   1    0    0    0
S3  0   0   4   0    0    0    0
S4  1   0   2   1    0    0    0
```

Is there a way of doing this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a perfect situation to use `apply` + `tabulate`, except for the inclusion of zeroes in your data and the need to include them.

Since you need to include tabulation of zeroes, you make a small modification to `tabulate` to start at zero instead of 1.

Here's a function that puts the approach in place:

```
DFTabulate <- function(indf) {
  nbins <- max(indf)
  `colnames<-`(t(apply(indf + 1, 1, tabulate, nbins = nbins + 1)), 0:nbins)
}
```

Here it is applied to your sample data.

```
DFTabulate(mydf)
#    0 1 2 3 4 5 6
# S1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1
# S2 0 1 2 1 0 0 0
# S3 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
# S4 1 0 2 1 0 0 0
```

---

You specify that you have a "large" `data.frame` but don't describe how large, so I'm not sure how relevant the following benchmark is.

However, just to share the logic behind using this approach: `tabulate` is generally a very fast function, so I thought I would make use of its efficiency.

Here's the benchmark:

```
set.seed(1)
nrow = 10000
ncol = 100
min = 0
max = 500
mydf <- data.frame(
  matrix(sample(min:max, nrow*ncol, TRUE), 
         nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, 
         dimnames = list(paste0("S", 1:nrow), paste0("ID", 1:ncol))))

fun2 <- function(df1 = mydf) {
  tbl <- table(c(row(df1)), factor(unlist(df1), levels=0:max))
  dimnames(tbl)[[1]] <- row.names(df1)
  tbl
}

fun3 <- function(df1 = mydf) mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1)))

system.time(DFTabulate(mydf))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.000   0.000   0.154 
system.time(fun2(mydf))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.000   0.000   1.018 
system.time(fun3(mydf))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.560   0.000   3.081
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `table`

```
table(c(row(df1)), unlist(df1))
#    0 1 2 3 4 6
#  1 0 0 2 0 1 1
#  2 0 1 2 1 0 0
#  3 0 0 4 0 0 0
#  4 1 0 2 1 0 0
```

If we need `0` and `5` also

```
tbl <- table(c(row(df1)), factor(unlist(df1), levels=0:6))
dimnames(tbl)[[1]] <- row.names(df1)
tbl
#
#     0 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  S1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1
#  S2 0 1 2 1 0 0 0
#  S3 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
#  S4 1 0 2 1 0 0 0
```

---

Another option is `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1)))
```

Comment: Beat me to it! All that needs to be changed in the above code would be switching levels to 0:6 instead of 1:6.

Comment: @M_Fidino  Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: Is it possible to retain the rownames(S1,S2..) in the output. And the range of the levels in known here, could it be possible to find the range of the levels from the data.

Comment: @chas I updated the solution.

Comment: Find range automatically from the data to be used for levels?

Comment: @chas you can try `Reduce(":",as.list(range(unique(sort(unlist(df1))))))`

Comment: It won't go below zero and there are zero's in the original data and need to be included